# Spinner Loader al ejecutar consulta

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<style>
    .loader {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      background: url('images/pageLoader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat 
      rgb(249,249,249);
      opacity: .8;
    }
</style>

<div class="loader"></div>

hola mundo

<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-success">salir</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

es una pagina de carga normal, el problema es que ese enlace me tiene que crear un archivo y se demora en salir de la pagina, hay forma de que al ejecutar ese evento, se levante un spinner loader pero para salir de ella, es decir la pagina queda [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] unos minutos antes de redireccionar y el usuario piensa que no esta haciendo nada. Y quisiera que notara que simplemente está ejecutándose un proceso antes de redireccionarlo.

Comment: La verdad no te entendí tu pregunta. Creo que deberías explicarte mejor. ¿Quieres hacer un spinner loader para cuando el proceso tarde en ejecutarse?

Comment: si, algo asi, apenas presiono el boton la pagina queda cargando y se demora en salir, la idea es que cuando esto suceda el usuario no se confunda y piense que no esta haciendo nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear un spinner. Hay varios ejemplos en internet para que puedas escoger y hacer, [acá algunos](https://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/). Luego solo ejecutas tu spinner en el momento de tu consulta y cuando haya sucedido, muestras lo que necesites.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('consultar');
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  circle.style.display = 'block';
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    circle.style.display = 'none';
    
    $('#data').html('Mis Datos fueron enviados');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.sk-circle {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
          animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
          transform: rotate(150deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
          transform: rotate(210deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
          transform: rotate(240deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
          transform: rotate(270deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
          transform: rotate(300deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
          transform: rotate(330deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
          animation-delay: -1.1s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
          animation-delay: -0.7s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
          animation-delay: -0.5s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
          animation-delay: -0.3s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
          animation-delay: -0.2s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
          animation-delay: -0.1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  } 40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  } 40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="consultar">Consultar</button>

<div class="sk-circle" style="display: none;" id="circle">
  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
</div>

<div id="data" style="margin: 3rem;"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba