# Mostrar un mensaje de espera mientras se publica via ajax

Tags: laravel, axios

estoy enviando un formulario a través de axios y al servidor en laravel, el cual a veces suele tardar un poco y da la sensación de que no está haciendo nada, cómo puedo hacer que el formulario se "bloquee" mientras axios espera una respuesta?

esta es la manera en la que ejecuto axios

```
            let formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('name', $("#name").val());
            formData.append('groups', $("#groups").val());
            formData.append('thumbnail', $('#thumbnail')[0].files[0]);
            formData.append('_method', 'PATCH');
            axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{route('groups.update', $locationGroup->id)}}',
                data: formData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' },
            }).then((response) => {
                if (response.data[0] === 'success') {
                    let groupId = response.data[1].locationGroupId;
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '{{__('groups.edit.success')}}',
                        icon: "success",
                    }).then(function () {
                        window.location.href = '/groups/' + groupId;
                    });
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = '/groups/' + groupId;
                    }, 5000);
                } else if (response.data.error){
                    showErrors(response.data.error);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '{{__('groups.error.name_duplicated.title')}}',
                        text: '{{__('groups.error.name_duplicated.text')}}',
                        icon: "error",
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

pienso utilizar la librería [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) para mostrar el mensaje de "espera...", sin embargo lo que necesito saber son dos cosas

1. Cómo puedo "bloquear" el formulario mientras axios espera la respuesta?
2. Mientras el formulario está bloqueado yo ejecutaré la ventana de sweetalert con un timeout o hasta que axios reciba una respuesta

Comment: Quizás esta respuesta te sirva de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443074/spinner-loader-al-ejecutar-consulta/443720#443720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar algo parecido a esto, este código esta en nuxtjs y element-ui pero te puede servir para que te guies

```
async submit() {
      this.loadingBtn = true
      await this.$axios.post('tudireccion', this.form).then(($data) => {
        this.$notify({
          title: 'Operacion Exitosa',
          message: 'Operacion Exitosa',
          type: 'success',
          position: 'top-right'
        })
      }).catch(error => {
        this.$notify.error({
          title: 'Error',
          message: 'Error',
          position: 'top-right'
        })
      }).then(() => {
        this.loadingBtn = false
      })
    }
```

para contestar tus dos preguntas finales:

1. Antes de llamar tu peticion axios puedes bloquear el boton de enviar el formulario, mostrar un preloader o lo que mejor te parezca, en el ejemplo estoy bloqueando el boton submit `this.loadingBtn = true`

Despues que terminar la petición vuelvo a activar el boton submit en el `then` con la linea `this.loadingBtn = false`

2. Como recomendación usa `async - await`

Comment: muchas gracias! :)